# Replacing last image tag or char with Regex

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex

I have this HTML string that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; direction: rtl; text-align: rtl; word-wrap: break-word">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    <img src="/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/7D48D94E-2FE5-4F66-AE29-B7E2EB30870B/MyApp.app/image003.png">&nbsp;
    <img src="/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/7D48D94E-2FE5-4F66-AE29-B7E2EB30870B/MyApp.app/image003.png">&nbsp;
    <img src="/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/7D48D94E-2FE5-4F66-AE29-B7E2EB30870B/MyApp.app/image003.png">&nbsp;
    <img src="/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/7D48D94E-2FE5-4F66-AE29-B7E2EB30870B/MyApp.app/image003.png">&nbsp;
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm building this string in the code by button click's and present it on a UIWebView. My problem is that I want to remove the last image from this string, but I don't know how. I think that the best way is to use Regular expression, but I don't know how to use it. Also I don't really know if it's possible, because I don't know what will be the last string, it could be just a char or it could be an image.

Someone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to remove the last `<img .../>` tag or the img src..?

Comment: yeah, but just the last one, without any thing else. The last <img src=""/> tag.

Comment: I don't think this is possible via pure RegEx since it doesn't match in reverse. You could *use* RegEx to store an array of substrings matching: `<img[^>]+>` then simply retrieve the last match.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
<img.*?>(?=[^<]*</body>)
```

That would match the last `<img>` tag based on it being followed by the `</body>` tag. As others have pointed out though, [parsing (x)html with regex is shady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) at best. Add some spaces into the `</body>` tag or a number of other things that would still be valid/correct html and the regex will fail.

A better solution would be to traverse the DOM and doing it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, I really don't know nothing about RegEx, I tried something but It's just removing all the <body> and <html> tags and leaving the <img..> tags. Can you please be more specific?